# How do I format row.names of an R table?

Tags: r, format, posixct, scientific-notation

Consider this `x` set of dates:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- sample(1980:2010, 100, replace = T)
x <- strptime(x, '%Y')
x <- strftime(x, '%Y')
```

The following is a distribution of the years of those dates:

```
> table(x)
x
1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1994 
   4    4    3    3    6    4    3    4    5   12    1    1    1    2 
1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 
   9    4    2    1    4    4    2    1    4    1    4    3    4    3 
2010 
   1
```

Now say I want to group them by decade. For this, I use the `cut` function:

```
> table(cut(x, seq(1980, 2010, 10)))
Error in cut.default(x, seq(1980, 2010, 10)) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Ok, so let's force `x` to numeric:

```
> table(cut(as.numeric(x), seq(1980, 2010, 10)))

(1.98e+03,1.99e+03]    (1.99e+03,2e+03]    (2e+03,2.01e+03] 
                 45                  28                  23
```

Now, as you can see, the `row.names` of that table are in scientific format. **How do I force them to not be in scientific notation?** I've tried wrapping that whole command above inside `format`, `formatC` and `prettyNum`, but all those do is format the frequencies.

Comment: `cut` has an argument called `dig.lab`.

Comment: Are you sure you used `set.seed()` here? I don't get the same results as you do.

Comment: You can just do `floor(x/10)*10`

Comment: @AnandaMahto, you're right, I wrote it here and forgot to use it in my R session. :$ Updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks joran for pointing the path to the answer. I'll elaborate it here for the record:

Changing `cut`'s `dig.lab` parameter from the default 3 to 4 solved this particular mockup as well as my real problem:

```
> table(cut(as.numeric(x), seq(1980, 2010, 10), dig.lab = 4))

(1980,1990] (1990,2000] (2000,2010] 
         45          28          23
```

By the way, in order for 1980 to be counted one should include the `include.lowest` argument:

```
> table(cut(as.numeric(x), seq(1980, 2010, 10), dig.lab = 4, include.lowest = T))

[1980,1990] (1990,2000] (2000,2010] 
         49          28          23
```

Now it sums to 100! :)

Comment: Note that this gives you wrong values. First, using `1980` as lower limit doesn't work because the value `1980` will not be included in any of `cut`'s groups because it is **exclusive**; it gives you `NA`. Second, a decade formally would go from `1980` to `1989` both inclusive, which is not what you get here.

Comment: I've just noticed that too, Julián; using `include.lowest = T` solves the problem. You're right about the decade division, I'm just not worried about that right now.

Comment: Consider using just `floor(as.numeric(x)/10)*10` or `as.numeric(x)-as.numeric(x)%%10`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer the question you asked, but shows you a possible alternative: use the fact that there is a `cut.Date` method:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- sample(1980:2010, 100, replace = T)
x <- strptime(x, '%Y')
out <- table(cut(x, "10 years"))
out
# 
# 1980-01-01 1990-01-01 2000-01-01 2010-01-01 
#         48         25         26          1
```

Here, we also get what I would consider the "correct" values for each bin.

---

As a crude justification of my statement about "correct" values, consider the values we get when we manually calculate based on `table`:

```
y <- strftime(x, '%Y')
Tab <- table(y)
Tab
# y
# 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1994 1995 1996 
#    4    4    3    3    6    4    3    4    5   12    1    1    1    2    9    4 
# 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2010 
#    2    1    4    4    2    1    4    1    4    3    4    3    1 
sum(Tab[grepl("198", names(Tab))])
# [1] 48
sum(Tab[grepl("199", names(Tab))])
# [1] 25
sum(Tab[grepl("200", names(Tab))])
# [1] 26
sum(Tab[grepl("201", names(Tab))])
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for bringing that up! Using `strptime` really adds `03-28` (today's March 28th) to the given year, instead of the `01-01` I thought it should. Your more elegant solution will probably come in handy in my future, but brute-forcing `x` to numeric yields easier-to-interpret row names (at least IMHO).

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio, no problem. Hopefully it comes in handy.